# RSpec test custom validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, validation, rspec-rails

I have the following validator in my model:

```ruby
class ContinuumValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if !record.end_time.nil? and record.end_time < record.start_time
      record.errors[:base] << "An event can not be finished if it did not start yet..."
    end
  end
end

class Hrm::TimeEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with ContinuumValidator
end
```

How can I test it using Rspec?

Here is what I have tried so far: (thanks to [zetetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387211/rspec-model-spec))

```ruby
describe "validation error" do
  before do
    @time_event = Hrm::TimeEvent.new(start_time: "2012-10-05 10:00:00", end_time: "2012-10-05 09:00:00", event_type: 2)
  end

  it "should not be valid if end time is lower than start time" do
    @time_event.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "raises an error if end time is lower than start time" do
    @time_event.errors.should include("An event can not be finished if it did not start yet...")
  end
end
```

But I get the following errors:

```
1) Hrm::TimeEvent validation error raises an error if end time is lower than start time
   Failure/Error: @time_event.errors.should include("An event can not be finished if it did not start yet...")

   expected #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fd1d8e02c50 @base=#<Hrm::TimeEvent id: nil, start_time: "2012-10-05 08:00:00", end_time: "2012-10-05 07:00:00", event_type: 2, employee_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, not_punched: false, validated: false, replace_id: nil>, @messages={}> to include "An event can not be finished if it did not start yet..."

   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
   -["An event can not be finished if it did not start yet..."]
   +#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fd1d8e02c50
   + @base=
   +  #<Hrm::TimeEvent id: nil, start_time: "2012-10-05 08:00:00", end_time: "2012-10-05 07:00:00", event_type: 2, employee_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, not_punched: false, validated: false, replace_id: nil>,
   + @messages={}>
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I achieve my goal?
Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that you're expecting `@time_event.errors` to behave like an array of strings. It doesn't, it returns ActiveModel::Errors. As others pointed out, you also need to trigger the validations with a call to `valid?`:

```
it "raises an error if end time is lower than start time" do
  @time_event.valid?
  @time_event.errors.full_messages.should include("An event can not be finished if it did not start yet...")
end
```

Comment: You're right I need to add the full_messages to get the error. However like the other said, I need to actually test the validation with `valid?`

Answer (score 3):

This solution works for me (using Mongoid):

**The model**

```
class OpLog
...
field :from_status, type: String
field :to_status,   type: String
...
validate :states_must_differ

def states_must_differ
  if self.from_status == self.to_status
    errors.add(:from_status, "must differ from 'to_status'")
    errors.add(:to_status, "must differ from 'from_status'")
  end
end
...
end
```

**The test:**

```
it 'is expected to have different states' do
  expect { create(:oplog, from_status: 'created', to_status: 'created').to raise_error(Mongoid::Errors::Validations) }
end
```

So in your case I'd write a test like this (if using ActiveRecord):

```
it 'raises an error if end time is lower than start time' do
  expect { create(Hrm::TimeEvent.new(start_time: "2012-10-05 10:00:00", end_time: "2012-10-05 09:00:00", event_type: 2)) }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::Errors)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no errors because you haven't called an event that triggers the errors. This happens normally when a record is created or saved. You may not want to hit the database in your test though and then you can use the method `valid?` like this:

```
it "raises an error if end time is lower than start time" do
  @time_event.valid?
  @time_event.errors.should include("An event can not be finished if it did not start yet...")
end
```

Me personally would put these two tests into one since valid? is called in the first case.

Also a minor: `if record.end_time` is better than `if !record.end_time.nil?`. (In my opinion at least.... :-) )

Comment: You are right, but like @Benjamin Sullivan suggested, I also need to add the full_messages to the errors so that my test pass. Thanks also for the minor :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the record wasnt validated therefore the validatior didn't run and no error was aded. You can see this in the code output. "validated: false"

try:

```
it "raises an error if end time is lower than start time" do
  @time_event.valid?
  @time_event.errors.should include("An event can not be finished if it did not start yet...")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not tested the validation actually, plus i would suggest you to make a single spec.

```
describe "validation error" do
  before { @time_event = Hrm::TimeEvent.new(start_time: "2012-10-05 10:00:00", end_time: "2012-10-05 09:00:00", event_type: 2) }

  it "raises an error if end time is lower than start time" do
    @time_event.valid?
    @time_event.errors.should include("An event can not be finished if it did not start yet...")
  end
end

class ContinuumValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.end_time and record.end_time < record.start_time
      record.error.add_to_base << "An event can not be finished if it did not start yet..."
    end
  end
end
```